# Connection refused error when calling a local web services in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am developing a web using Angular. I can connect my local node service (Local PC) to my local host web(HTTP & local PC).

But I am unable to connect to the node service (Public server) on the web(HTTPS & Public server). I am getting a "connection refused" error.

Also, I cannot connect using my domain name (On the public server). But I can connect the node service using the domain name from another pc.

Code (API call in angular js)

```
  $http.post('http://localhost:port/api', {
        data:"data"
    })
  .then(function(response){console.log(response)});
```

Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enought info here to help you, likely a configuration issue on the server

Comment: Can you plz tell me what other information you need? One thing, I can access the node server using the curl command, but not in angular.